# Can I configure Google Drive Finder integration to copy files rather than move them?

Tags: google-drive

Using OSX, when I drag a file to or from the Google Drive folder, it moves the file rather than copying it. I can't think of any occasion where I want that behaviour, and it's very frustrating when working with shared folders - I keep deleting files for other people! Can I change that behaviour?

Comment: Because you're not asking about the Web interface, but rather the OS client, this question is off-topic here. It would be better served on [su] or [apple.se].

Comment: @AlE. Fair enough - voted to close.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.   That's how Google Drive is designed to work.   You need to think of the Google Drive folder as a shared one, not your own private little workspace.

If that's too hard, then you need to work with drive thru your web-browser only, not through the integrated Folder.

Comment: That's a pain. I *do* think of it as a shared folder, that's precisely why I want different behaviour from the default. Dropbox's integration does The Right Thing - i.e. always copies rather than moves - so it's certainly possible. Copying using the mouse/trackpad alone is much more awkward than the standard drag+drop.

Comment: We could argue for hours about what The Right Thing is, but every shared or network drive folder I've worked on for 20+ years has functioned the way that Drive is working now, ie when you work on a file in the folder, you work on that file, not a copy.   If you want a copy, you have to make it (open the file and Save As or similar command)

Comment: Well, I don't want to have that argument :) And I might not have explained myself perfcetly, but accessing a drive on a server in OSX most certainly does *not* act in the same way as Google Drive. If I drag+drop a file from a connected server to a local directory, it *copies*.